# Nocioception (pain perception) in subcutaneous tissue

Tags: neuroscience, neurology

There seem to be no nocioceptors (pain and temperature sensitive nerve endings) in subcutaneous fat. there are nocioceptors and other receptors in veins running through fat, but these can be avoided. Does this mean that subcutaneous fat can be cut, or otherwise traumatised, such as with diathermy (burning) without causing pain?

Comment: No nerves no pain I guess...

Answer (score 1):

> *"no nociceptors in subcutaneous fat"*

Well nerves innervate tissue, but only the layers of skin above the hypodermis (Subcuteaneous fat layer).

**You are correct**.

If one was to burn below this layer they would not feel pain in that area due to having no nociceptors.

There is a great Kharn Academy video on this topic [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/test-prep/mcat/organ-systems/integumentary-system/v/what-lies-beneath-the-epidermis-dermis-and-hypodermis).